# How to solve this situation where bitbake do_fetch() is freezing or stopping, with Yocto and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, raspberry-pi3, meta-raspberrypi

I ran the command

```
bitbake core-image-minimal
```

[image: terminal screen shot]

This is my step:

```
git clone poky
git clone meta-raspberrypi
source oe-init-build-env rpi-build
rpi-build/conf/bblayer.conf # adding meta-raspberrypi
rpi-build/conf/local.conf # modify MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi3"
bitbake core-image-minimal # (actually I also ran other image "rpi-hwup-image", "core-image-full-cmdline")
```

How can I do this problem?

```
$ps aux | grep core-image-minimal

 18925  0.1  0.5 153504 41724 pts/2    S+   17:05   0:00 python /opt/sungsoo/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake core-image-minimal
 18937  0.7  1.6 322408 136508 pts/2   Sl+  17:05   0:04 python /opt/sungsoo/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake core-image-minimal
```

Comment: Bitbake has probably not crashed, it's just that the folks behind Raspberry Pi have created an enormous git-repository, with lots of binary files. It takes a **long** time to clone...

Comment: Thanks Anders. solve this problem...you'r right.

Comment: Ok, I'm adding my comment as an answer, so you can mark it as accepted (and thus solved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitbake has probably not crashed, it's just that the folks behind Raspberry Pi have created an enormous git-repository, with lots of binary files. It takes a long time to clone...

If I remember correctly, the bootfiles are taken from the Raspberry Pi [firmware repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware). My bare clone is currently 5.4GiB...